# JQuery UI & Cordova & ASP.NET

Tags: jquery, asp.net, visual-studio, cordova

I just need to get my head around this, am I correct in saying that in theory, I could create an ASP.NET website, use JQuery Mobile to provide my mobile interface consistency and Cordova to provide my website access to core mobile functionality? Essentially creating something which looks and works like a Mobile App but is in fact entirely cloud based?

Have I got this right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can still build your website in ASP and use jQuery Mobile to make a very mobile friendly web application, but that is different than a creating a hybrid mobile app, which is what Cordvoa supports. The Cordova framework still has to run as an app on the mobile device.

Just including the cordova.js in your website doesn't give your web application access to native mobile device features. Behind the scenes, Cordova uses some platform specific code to give its JavaScript interfaces the real functionality. So Cordova still actually has to be on the user's device as part of a mobile app.

Mobile web applications still just run in a browser and are sandboxed from doing anything outside of what a typical browser would let any other website do. Hybrid applications will commonly use a browser to provide the frontend of the app but are actually running natively and have access to the native features.

Comment: Appreciation can always be expressed in Upvotes for the answer or accepting it as the solution. :)